# What is the function of http://macbook-pro.local:7001/weblogic/?

Tags: weblogic12c

I found that weblogic defaults to a context "/weblogic/", there is nothing in this page, what does this do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIfBo.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you hit /weblogic, you hit the ReadyApp monitoring servlet under /weblogic/ready context.
In short, this servelet exposes the status of your applications deployed in your application server.
Http code 200 means that your server and your app are started and ready to handle incoming requests.
You can read details about the ReadyApp framework in this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/DEPGD/managing.htm#DEPGD299).